# "oledb exception was unhandled" from the "Public Sub connection() cn. open"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module modConnection

    Public cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Public cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader

    Public Sub connection()
        cn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        With cn
            .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Employee Management System\ems.accdb"
            .Open()
        End With
    End Sub
End Module
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim msg As String
        msg = MsgBox("Are you sure ?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        If msg = vbYes Then
            Me.Hide()
            Login.Show()
        Else
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call connection()

        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Public relations")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Leagal")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Marketing")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Finance")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Administration")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Information Technology")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Production")

        ComboBox2.Items.Add("Male")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("Female")

        ComboBox3.Items.Add("")

        ComboBox4.Items.Add("Islam")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("Christian")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("Hindu")

        ComboBox5.Items.Add("Production")
        ComboBox5.Items.Add("Public relations")
        ComboBox5.Items.Add("Leagal")
        ComboBox5.Items.Add("Marketing")
        ComboBox5.Items.Add("Finance")
        ComboBox5.Items.Add("Administration")
        ComboBox5.Items.Add("Information Technology")

        ComboBox7.Items.Add("Production")
        ComboBox7.Items.Add("Public relations")
        ComboBox7.Items.Add("Leagal")
        ComboBox7.Items.Add("Marketing")
        ComboBox7.Items.Add("Finance")
        ComboBox7.Items.Add("Administration")
        ComboBox7.Items.Add("Information Technology")


    End Sub
    Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
        Try

            cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            With cm
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO employee (First Name,Midle Name,Last Name) VALUES (@First Name,@Midle Nam,@Last Name)"

                '.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Snum", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.txtSearch.Text))
                .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@First Name", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.TextBox2.Text))
                .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Midle Name", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.TextBox3.Text))
                .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Last Name", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.TextBox4.Text))


                ' RUN THE COMMAND
                'cm.Parameters("@Snum").Value = Me.txtSearch.Text
                cm.Parameters("@First Name").Value = Me.TextBox2.Text
                cm.Parameters("@Midle Name").Value = Me.TextBox3.Text
                cm.Parameters("@Last Name").Value = Me.TextBox4.Text


                cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Record saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                Me.TextBox2.Text = ""
                Me.TextBox3.Text = ""
                'Me.txtSearch.Text = ""
                Me.TextBox4.Text = ""
                Exit Sub
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Next time you ask a question could you be a little clearer and not include _all_ of your code but the code that the issue is relevant too. The method you had an issue with `connection` would have been just fine. Since you are new, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and have a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

There's no question here but I assume by the title that your code is failing on the cn.Open(). This answer addresses this issue alone.

There are 2 things stopping you opening the database...

1. The database location is amalgamated with the Application.StartupPath. I'm not sure why you've done that but take it out.
2. You cannot open a 2007+ Ms/Access database using the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver. Use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 instead.

Thus your code becomes...

```
With cn
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Employee Management System\ems.accdb"
    .Open()
End With
```